# How can I open Camera Roll in pop up window in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, imessage, camera-roll

I develop a messaging application and want to open a Camera Roll interface in the pop-up window similar to iMessage app:
[image]

How can I achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope this works for you

//initialize image picker and add to popover controller

```
  UIImagePickerController* imagePickerController= [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];   
    imagePickerController.delegate=self;    
    imagePickerController.sourceType= UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary; 
popoverController= [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagePickerController];
   [popoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```